# Is it true that "[s]hell scripts put the source code right out in the open for all the world to see"? How come?

Tags: bash, security

I am somewhat of a beginner with Bash scripting so I was reading Advanced Bash Scripting Guide by Mendel Cooper. In page 2 he mentions that

> Shell scripts put the source code right out in the open for all the
>   world to see.

He also mentions one should not use Bash in the following case:

> Situations where security is important, where you need to guarantee the integrity of your system and
>   protect against intrusion, cracking, and vandalism

I don't understand why that is the case. Can someone explain and give examples?

Comment: "All the world to see" is a bit strong. The person that needs to run the script can see its contents (same as with any interpreted language, and not really different in the case of compiled languages against a dedicated attacker with a disassembler). People "on the Internet" cannot. I am not sure protecting the system against people that already have shell access (and the necessary user-level permissions to do what the script needs to do) is an attack scenario you need to worry about too much.